# upcrossing inequality for positive submartingale

Tags: inequality, stochastic-processes, martingales

I have a little problem with this Lemma. I have to show: 
Let be X nonnegative Supermartingale, then
$$E(U_{a,b}(X))≤\frac{a}{(b-a)}$$
$\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0 ≤ a < b$, while $U_{a,b}(X)$ called the number of upcrossing of [a,b]

Thank you very much in advance for your answer!

Comment: You are asking for a proof of a standard result. If you have difficulty in understanding the proof you should tell us where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here. My idea was: 

$$(b-a)E(U_{a,b}(X))≤E(H \bullet X)_\beta+E(X_\beta-a)^- ≤ E(X_\beta-a)^- ≤ E(|X_n|) + a$$, while H is the indicator funktion and $E(|X_n|)≤0$ because of X is a supermartingale. What du you think about it?

Comment: You cannot have $E|X_n| \leq 0$ unless $X_n=0$  almost surely.

Comment: The standard upcrossings inequality of Doob gives the upper bound $\frac {EX_1+b} {b-a}$. The stated inequality (which does not involve  $\{X_n\}$) seems doubtful.

Comment: it was a only idea I had to show this statement. Are you able to give me impetus to what I have to do?

Comment: but how can i show, that
$$\frac{EX_1+b}{b-a}≤\frac{a}{b-a}$$ ? I'm really confused now.

Comment: $EX_1+b \geq b >a$ so there is no hope of proving any such thing. Give us some context for this question. Where did you find it?

Comment: this is one of the task of the book "Martingale in diskreter Zeit" from Harald Luschgy. But this is a book in german language.

Comment: I've already showed this inequality for X supermartingale

$$(b−a)E(U_{a,b}(X))≤E(H∙X)_\beta+E(X_\beta−a)^−≤E(X_\beta−a)−$$ 

I thought, it will be a similar way to proof this task I've already wrote on the top of this post.

Comment: Actually, $(t-a)^{-} \leq a$ for any non-negative real number $t$. So if you are sure about the inequality you have derived then you have got the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! you made my day ;)